# How to check gems ready to update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Ho to check gems ready to update, without update them?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you are not using bundler, just run `gem outdated` and it will give you a list of outdated gems.

Example of output:

```
$ gem outdated                                                                                                                                                                                   
acts_as_tree (2.7.1 < 2.9.1)                                                                                                                                                                     
addressable (2.4.0 < 2.7.0)                                                                                                                                                                      
bcrypt (3.1.12 < 3.1.13)                                                                                                                                                                         
bootsnap (1.4.5 < 1.4.6)                                                                                                                                                                         
bootstrap (4.3.1 < 4.4.1)                                                                                                                                                                        
brakeman (4.7.2 < 4.8.0)                                                                                                                                                                         
cancancan (1.17.0 < 3.0.2)                                                                                                                                                                       
chart_js (1.1.0 < 1.1.1)                                                                                                                                                                         
coffee-rails (4.2.2 < 5.0.0)
combustion (0.6.0 < 1.1.2)
database_cleaner (1.8.2 < 1.8.3)
...
```

Answer (score 9):

Bundler has an [outdated](http://gembundler.com/v1.1/bundle_outdated.html) command. I assume you're using Bundler, of course.

Comment: Updated link: https://bundler.io/man/bundle-outdated.1.html

Answer (score 2):

`gem outdated` will give you a list of outdated gems including version number you currently have and the latest version number.

Then to update:

- `gem update GEMNAME` to update a specific gem
  or just
- `gem update` to update all gems to the latest stable version

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy, just type the following code:

```
$ gem update GEMNAME
```

Comment: Op said without actually updating the gem. By the way, welcome to SO! You're off to a great start, answering instead of asking.

Comment: Thanks Linuxios, I really should have taken care of that :)